# Where is the animation play button in 2.7?

Tags: animation, interface

I was used to press the play button for a preview of a rendered animation

[image],

all of a sudden (v2.7) there is an audio button  which opens a file dialog. Am I supposed to add all images into the VSE every time?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can instead use the option in *Info > Render > Play rendered animation*, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>

[image]